# Can we use the Halbach array configuration in an electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, power-engineering, electrical, magnetic-flux

I tried asking this question in several forums but didn't find any answers as i expected. It's very hard to find information about halbach array in google, especially in the electromagnetic field.

We know that Halbach array works well with a permanent magnet by giving a strong magnetic field in one side and weak on the other side.

I'm thinking to design solenoid in halbach arrangement to give a strong magnetic field in one side and weak in the other. We know that solenoid behave similarly to permanent magnet. My question what happens when we give alternative current or pulsed dc to solenoid coil? Will the direction change in magnetic field? I know pulsed dc doesn't change in magnetic field? Will this be a problem to achieve halbach array? kindly advise.

Comment: YOU'D HAVE TO GIVE SOME IDEA OF THE WAVEFORMS OF THE VARIOUS COILD TO GET A GOOD IDEA - AND WHAT YOU WERE TRYING TO ACHIEVE.

Comment: Your stated subject is far less complex than your body text. DC electro magnets with well defined fields - probbly no problem. |Add AC and the fun begins: Applying identical wave sinusoidal signals to solenoids in a Halbach array seems likely to preserve the effects - which are only a result of arithmetic addition. Affects on amplitude of field due to adjacent magnetic materials may well be an issue. | Pulsed DC would be more problematic as the behaviour of field rise and decay would probably be complicated by overall arrangement.

Comment: I'm trying to create a wireless transmitter using halbach arrangement to produce a magnetic field. I was thinking if we can find a good solution with Halbach arrangement, it will give a high-density magnetic field on one side which will be beneficial for wireless power transmission technologies. This can also increase efficiency but i don't have any idea beside solenoid design. The major drawback with halbach in electromagnetic field is the eddy current and positioning. I was hoping pulsed dc would be an ideal way to get the result. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: OK - you reasons for wanting it make sense. Fortunately, with near field coupling, which you have in almost all such applications, you do not get radiation without a load, and at receiver resonance you get excellent power transfer. [[25+ years ago I built a demonstration inductive power transfer system with a 100m loop running around my house and the ability to drop receivers appropriately anywhere along the way. I also had highish speed bidirectionl data signalling across the loop - another story]. Receiver resonance is essentially essential.

Comment: Thank you for answering. You did a great job with the 100m loop where you can charge a device at anywhere. I'm thinking to use receiver resonance and transmitter resonance but with halbach arrangement for the transmitter since it give us good magnetic field density. What's your suggestion? My idea is to use Halbach AC arrangement for the transmitter. Any suggestion or idea would be useful for my research purpose.

Comment: start with RX resonance and see how it works - you may not need any more than that. What distance, what power level? What frequency?

Comment: My transmitter is operating between 66-100 kHz with pulsed DC. Transferring power is between 30 to 40 watts and between 10mm distance. I'm using ring transmitter and planar receiver coil.

Comment: Resonant secondary is your great friend. Primary can be series or parallel resonaned.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. My last question, What is the efficiency you achieve with a resonant primary and secondary with 5mm gap. We know traditional chargers get between 70-77% efficiency. What is the highest efficiency you received in your research? Is it possible to achieve 90% for 30 to 40 watts output excluding the conversion losses in the receiver and transmitter. Only the flux efficiency.

Comment: At 25+ years ago the details blur. The aim there was more proof of concept than utter optimum performance (although that mattered too). I could look and see if I could find anything useful in old documentation - but it's likely that others have published much on this since. Resonance achieves magic and near field coupling more magic - as you get minimal losses when there is no transmission, unlike RF (properly inter-elated E&M fields) which you "throw out there" regardless and then try to intercept. ie flux efficiency is high as you use it mainly only for actual transfer. But, resonate!

Comment: FWIW: I originally was lectured on the subject by a very early pioneer (not Tesla :-) ) about 49 years ago (!!!!) and then did nothing with it until 20+ years later. The original man was Dr Otto of Auckland University NZ and his name is very little seen in the literature for complex "political & patent reasons" - and the name you do see (which I'll not mention) has lots of interesting history behind it. In 1972 I "drove" a small induction powered (zero battery) vehicle ("go kart") along a university corridor :-). Not something you'll see much mention of now. Suppressed knowledge :-) :-) :-).

Comment: Yes - here is the patent that shows the details: https://patents.google.com/patent/US7598646B2/en

Answer (score 1):

Halbach array is an alternative to backiron. Backiron closes the loop leaving tiny field on the back side. Halbach closes the loop by force.
Is backiron a problem for you?
Halbach is more complicated than backiron, i.e. more expensive. In the permanent magnet case it may be created by magnetisation field shape in a single part hence it can be a useful method (refrigerator magnet). With discrete permanent magnets it is a choice between backiron and twice as many magnets. With electromagnets you are talking about twice as much copper. Take your pick. One way or the other the advantage is likely to be small.

Comment: "backiron" returns a rather low amount of results.. Can you elaborate on the subject a bit more or provide a link with details please?

Answer (score 0):

" "backiron" returns a rather low amount of results"
Well, fancy that!
The topic of interest is Magnetic Circuits.
Analogous to electric current flowing around loops.
Magnetic fields form loops.
Iron, and multiple other materials, presents a "low impedance" to magnetic field.
A block of iron behind an electromagnet closes the loops of the field of the electromagnet such that very little of the field extends beyond the iron.
The intermediate magnets of a halbach array confine the field less effectively than iron does. But in certain cases the array may be preferable. e.g. possibly cheaper, possibly simpler, possibly less massive.